# Cant connect to my PLEX Media server outside my network

Tags: server, windows-media-server

iam currently trying to make a plex media server, ive been using windows 8.1 because that was the installation i had laying around. but now i think ive tried everything to make it working outside my network. 
when i "connect" on the plex  it shows: 
[image]

so i guess it knows my server, and it knows my public ip and what ports to use, but still no internet? ive talked a friend and he said he sat the remote access port on the server, but i dont think i have that option on win8.

what ive tried:

port forwarding 32400

set up firewall to allow 32400

putting the server in a DMZ

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was double NAT at my ISP :-)